# Android AccountManager: peekAuthToken

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, accountmanager

I have implemented an account manager in Android, and I'm using the peekAuthToken a lot inside the application, to get the token.

But I'm a bit confused about in the source code, in the docs it says:

> Intended for use by the authenticator, not directly by applications.

Why is that, and what will be the issue using this method to get the authToken?

Comment: why not using getAuthToken?

Comment: I'm wondering why use it if peekAuthToken works, what is the harm of not using it?

Comment: if they say "Intended for use by the authenticator, not directly by applications." i believe they know what the say

Comment: Alright, I wanted to know more about the underlying structure, why one is discourage from calling. But I trust the docs too.

Comment: @JoakimEngstrom have you found an answer? I'm facing the same issue. Did you have any problem using peekAuthToken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`peekAuthToken` internally checks that two uids are equal before providng the auth token:

- the uid of the app that is requesting the auth token
- the uid of the app that provided the Authentication IBinder (i.e., the uid that manages the account)

If the uids are different, you'll get a SecurityException.

In other words, if you're shipping the Authentication Service with the rest of your app, you should be fine.  (Though I'd still recommend using `getAuthToken` instead).  However, if you're shipping the Authenticator in one app and want to call `peekAuthToken` in another, that will not work.

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/4535e11fb7010f2b104d3f8b3954407b9f330e0f/services/core/java/com/android/server/accounts/AccountManagerService.java#L1544